# How do I detect if keyboard is currently shown, if I transitioned from another view controller that was already showing the keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, uitextfield, nsnotification

I have a view controller that makes a UITextField firstResponder on ViewWillAppear. Normally I could just rely on a UIKeyboardWillShow notification to detect if the keyboard has shown, but this won't trigger if I came into the current view controller while the keyboard was already showing.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: in viewWillDisappear just dismiss the keboard by using [self.view endEditing:YES]

Answer (score 8):

I noticed while debugging view hierarchy that when keyboard is presented there's `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow` in hierarchy.

First we can add extension to UIApplication to check window hierarchy for `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow`:

```
extension UIApplication {
    var isKeyboardPresented: Bool {
        if let keyboardWindowClass = NSClassFromString("UIRemoteKeyboardWindow"), self.windows.contains(where: { $0.isKind(of: keyboardWindowClass) }) {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Then in `viewDidLoad`, or where needed we can check:

```
if UIApplication.shared.isKeyboardPresented {
   print("Keyboard is presented")
}
```

---

**Although this method is not fully tested and `UIRemoteKeyboardWindow` is in private headers that's why `NSClassFromString` is needed for check. Use it with concern!**

Comment: This works in many cases except when iOS email modal is invoked. Canceling the modal does returns keyboard presented true although it should be false

Answer (score 4):

When you enter in a `textField`, it becomes first responder and then the keyboard will appears on your view. You can check the status of the keyboard in your `viewWillAppear` method [textField isFirstResponder]. If it returns YES, means your keyboard is visible.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     if([textField isFirstResponder]){
       //visible keyboard
     }
}
```

**Edited**
If you want the height than you can store the keyboard height in some class variable when it appears first time and use in `viewWillAppear` method

```
@implementation YourClass{
    CGFloat keyboardSize;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
     [super viewWillAppear:animated];
     if([textField isFirstResponder]){
        //user keyboardSize here
     }
}
```

Comment: Not necessarily, if a hardware keyboard is used then the software keyboard will not be shown. Additionally, I'd like the actual notification to happen so that I could find the actual size of the keyboard on display.